# Eww! Has it crossed the pond yet?

Tags: etymology, american-english, british-english, exclamations

I hear *eww* (sometimes spelt as *ew*) fairly regularly on American sitcoms, usually uttered by a scatterbrained beautiful blonde girl when she sees or hears something disgusting. I don't recall it ever being said when I was a child living in London, and the word *gross* was virtually unknown. In the 1970s, the utterances *[yuck](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/yuck)* or *[ugh](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ugh)* were commonly blurted out. Moreover, on my frequent visits to the UK I don't seem to hear *eww* ever being used but I tend to mix with people closer to my age.

The dictionary, [Online Etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/) offers no guidance, and Oxford Dictionaries limits itself by saying

> ### ew
>
> /ˈɪəuː/, /ˈiːuː/
>
> **EXCLAMATION**
>
> <sup>INFORMAL</sup>
>   Used to express disgust or distaste:
>   *ew, I’d hate to think what has been trampled into that carpet*
>   *eww, how can you eat that?*
>
> ---
>
> **Origin**
>
> 1970s: imitative.

Has *ew/eww* crossed the Atlantic and become common parlance in old Blighty i.e. the UK? If it has, when did it more or less occur? And are the expressions *ugh* and *yuck* still popular with the young in both the US and the UK? If not, which exclamation of disgust is gaining territory?

If  anyone is still confused about which sound I'm referring to, click on the YouTube link to hear a perfect example. The young *American* child (who coincidently happens to be blonde) is called Georgie and she is tasting a variety of foods while blindfolded, the resulting  *"eww!"* is spontaneous and unaffected and happens at 56 seconds.

<sup>[EWW! THAT'S GROSS!](http://youtu.be/UL5-soS7kos?t=53s)</sup>

Comment: The "ewww" thing seemed to come into popularity in the 1980s with the emergence of Valley Girl-speak (California, US).  Jimmy Fallon (US late night talk show host) recently reprised this era with a skit of a pretend talk show called "EWWW": http://youtu.be/sIhU3mQTp1U  you're sure to get your fill of "ewww" here! lol!

Comment: The earliest evidence of the word found by the OED‘s researchers dates from 1978, in a reporting of children’s speech.  Washington Post 8 Sept. (Weekend section) 6/1   ‘Ewwww,’ said the kids. ‘They don’t have very many manners.’http://public.oed.com/appeals/ew/

Comment: I can't speak for the UK as of the past 7 years, but in the US both *ew* and *yuck* are used.  *Ew* more as a quick thoughtless reaction to something gross, and *yuck* more as an intentional reaction.  *Ugh* is used as an expression of exasperation or annoyance.  *Ugh, I can't enter this as an answer since I cannot address usage in the UK*.

Comment: To all: Thank you so much for the amusing and interesting comments so far.

Comment: Depending how many w's you use in spelling, a quick fiddle with Ngram has it being around since the 1900's, with a preference for 'eww' in BE and 'ewww' in AE. As for crossing the pond... I live and work in SEA and it is commonplace here, so it has done more than just cross the Atlantic - assuming it isn't a universal sound that has no particular origin.

Comment: It's also crossed into other languages entirely (@Roaring, you don't specify whether it's just used in English in Indonesia, or also in Indonesian?): it is becoming exceedingly common among younger people in all of Scandinavia (in the native languages), though it is still identifiably English-sounding.

Comment: What @Roaring Fish said. H G Wells used it in [Experiment in Autobiography, 1934](https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/w/wells/hg/experiment_in_autobiography/chapter4.html) with the then-standard spelling: *“**Eugh**!” My life went to the refrain of Mr. Key’s disgusted “**Eugh**.”*

Comment: Janus... as far as I can see, it is used in Indonesian, and Chinese, and Malay, though there is something of the Observers Dilemma here, as in I don't know how common it is in Indonesia when there isn't this white guy listening!

Comment: Is this question about the *sound itself*, or is it about the most common orthographic representation and/or the tendency of some people to align their speech patterns with a written form rather than what they and their linguistic community actually *articulate*?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Written language is merely a meta-representation of oral language (which is merely a meta-representation of thought). It's the meme! However it's expressed.

Comment: Answers? @RoaringFish I'd be very careful with Ngrams before asserting that *eww* and *ewww* existed in the 1900s. They might be OCR errors or acronyms. Fumblefingers, to me, **eugh** looks like a spelling variant of **ugh**?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I care not how many Ws ew is spelled or spelt; *ew!* is pronounced differently from *ugh!*, they are not the same. Which sound do the Brits utter nowadays? I think my question will be difficult to answer because these type of "grunts" (for want of a better word) were rarely transcribed, so I'll be happy with any  personal experience British native speakers could provide.

Comment: Has anyone else seen or heard "ewww" used as an expression of delight or admiration? I remember seeing some impressive graffiti on the side of a building and next to it someone else had spray-painted a large anime-style drawing of a skateboarder with a caption bubble that said (admiringly) "Ewww Thats Fresh!" This was maybe 15 years ago in Berkeley, California, so I'm sure the particular slang usage is generations out-of-date by now.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: You yourself commented earlier that you consider ***eugh*** to be just a spelling variant of ***ugh***, which suggests you have a pretty loose approach to the relationship between onomatopoeic orthography and pronunciation. When did people start making the vowel-less "plosive" **/tsk/**, as opposed to various other sounds that previously were normally transcribed as **tut**? How much does onomatopoeia start to copy orthography, as opposed to the other way around?

Comment: Personally, I almost never actually *say* the sound you're asking about here. But as from 15 years ago when I started spending time on chat sites, I quickly got into the habit of writing **ew** because it was quick, easy, and "close enough". A year later I met a couple of the people I'd been chatting to for so many hours via text. Two of us thought it was a bit weird that the (younger) third guy actually *said* "ew" quite often, since we didn't (we both made the same different noise that we couldn't transcribe). The younger guy watched US TV series *Friends*, so we guessed he got it from there

Comment: Mari-Lou... as well as being a bit condescending there - what makes you assume I don't know anything about corpora? - I did say it was from Ngram so it is not me asserting anything. It is me investigating in the quickest and easiest way whether your assumption that 'eww' began in the states is actually true and reporting what Ngram said. Plus, whatever the shortcomings of Ngram, the assumption that it is always wrong is logically indefensible.

Comment: @RoaringFish I've been burnt in the past with Ngrams and Google etc. I was merely being "nice", you know? It's comments, sharing experiences, opinions, thoughts etc. Character space is limited and all that, and I'm taking 1900s to mean 1900-1920, not 1980s.

Comment: I vaguely recall Eliza Doolittle saying it in _My Fair Lady_. Am I imagining it? Does that not count because it was written by an American, who might not have known British dialects too well?

Comment: The script for _Pygmalion_ has Eliza Doolittle say at various times “Ah-ow-oo-ooh!” “Ah-ah-ah-ow-ow-ow-oo!” “Aaaaaah-ow-ooh! Aaaaaaaaaaaah-ow-ooh!!!” “Ah-ah-ah-ow-ow-oo!”, and “Ah-ah-ah-ah-ow-ow-oo-oo!!!” Some of her utterances might be heard as a stylized “Ew” or “Ewwwwwww!”

Comment: In addition, _Pygmalion_ contains two instances of “phew!” and one instance of “whew!” but no instances of “ew!” From Act 1: “_The Gentleman._ Phew!” From Act 2: "_Pickering._ Phew! I say!” From Act 5, “_Higgins._ The devil he does! Whew!” It also calls for multiple characters to say “Oh” (which in the theatre or on film may be rendered in very different accents).

Comment: @FumbleFingers getting pretty desperate here! Only one new answer since I launched the bounty. Why not try your hand at answering this one? I liked your previous comment, you even pinpointed *ew's migration to fifteen years ago*, and I upvoted it, too. Go on... pleeeaze!

Comment: @Mari-Lou: From my perspective I'm not really qualified to answer this one. In my *opinion* the "ee-oo" pronunciation is an "American teenage girl" affectation popularised there a couple of decades ago, but I don't actually *know* that. In fact, for all I know it might have started in Australia or somewhere else (I honestly don't think it *started* in the UK). But if no-one else can nail it any more definitively I'll throw my tuppence-worth in within the next three days!

Comment: I can make no comments on British usage (I never knew it wasn't an accepted expression in the U.K), but I am glad that *ew* has made it to Oxford Online.  I lost a Scrabble challenge on the word a few years back; despite everyone in the room (Canadians) agreeing on the definition and most accepting the spelling, it wasn't in any of the dictionaries consulted. I'll know which dictionary to use as a reference next time.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: It's not much of an "answer", because I think it's almost impossible to know how prevalent a usage like this is outside your own particular linguistic circle. You can't trust written forms, and downmarket TV/radio may be particularly likely to overplay such "affectations". By which I mean I think **/ˈiː(j)uː/** is like **/jʌk/** *("Yuck!")*. If you're truly "caught off-guard" by something disgusting, you're not likely to emit such a carefully enunciated sound as a *genuine, visceral, natural* expression. It's more like a "conventionally understood" imitation of the real thing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers well the video which I posted I thought illustrated quite well the *ew* sound. It's as if the child's mind has been programmed/conditioned to project that noise. Talking from personal experience, I've never uttered similar sound in my life. My emissions (!) sound more like *eughs*. I just find the *eww* sound very unnatural to repeat, I have to consciously force myself to imitate it. Anyhoo, thank you so much for your intelligent input.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Ha! I bet you never used ***anyhoo*** back when you were a teenager! When ***I*** was a teenager, that was just uneducated/regional dialect, but it's [shot to prominence in the past couple of decades](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anyhoo&year_start=1950&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canyhoo%3B%2Cc0). It's positively *rife* in [Family Guy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Guy) these days - affectations are *fun!*

Comment: I remember hearing "eww" from relatives in the Los Angeles area as early as 1971, but never saw it spelled until the 90s.

Comment: I do not pronounce 'eww' as given (and I don't hear it that way either. I don't pronounce it exactly like the 'yew' tree, but rather as /yw/ or a high front rounded vowel followed by bilabial glide (in GenAmE).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It has definitely crossed over to the UK. My 15 year old (a couple of years ago) daughter used it as expression of choice when faced with a gross situation. Sadly I have even used it myself but I like to think in a post-modern ironic sense ;)

Like many Americanisms that cross the pond I imagine it is likely to have transferred through TV programmes, such as Friends.

Comment: I've just asked a British friend of mine and he's hypothesized that it's become popular largely due to the cartoon series The Simpson's. What do you think?

Comment: Certainly American TV, but with so much to choose from it would be difficult to pin down a direct single influence. I would probably add Friends to the list of prime suspects :)

Comment: I agree. Eww! Yuk! and Ugh! are all now common in the UK.

Comment: @MarvMills I first became aware of Eww through watching *Friends*. My children all use it, though growing up in Wales they also say ['Ych a fi'](http://cyw.s4c.co.uk/ych-a-fi/en_index.shtml)

Comment: @Mynamite  I used to love watching *Friends*, but it was dubbed in Italian (shown on RAI) and long before DVDs were released. That might explain why I've only noticed this sound in recent years.

Comment: Marv Mills, if you could include the TV series, Friends, as being one of the prime suspects it would strengthen your answer. Comments have a nasty habit of being suddenly deleted if anyone flags them as being "obsolete" or "chatty". I don't think yours will, but... if you could edit your post, I would sleep easier tonight :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well I wouldn't want you to have any sleepless nights, so I have amended my answer accordingly :)

Answer (score 6):

I’m a 62 year old (U.S. Male); the term ew or eww, as described, is equivalent to yuck in a more tactile sense. You may react to a slimy frog being offered to you, to hold; with the opportunity to say no, with Yuck!, as a response. But if a crass person just says here, hold this, without description, or knowledge of what it is, and you hold out your hand as a trusting person, the term ew or eww is likely to be used, when you actually feel the slimy creature placed in your hand.

This is an excellent question about word usage in context.

This response is strictly my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, it doesn't exactly answer my question but it does clarify how *eww* is different from *yuck* which is good to know.

Answer (score 6):

At school in England around the turn of the millenium, "eww" was certainly in usage. I think (as mentioned in the comments) the huge popularity of US television shows may have had something to do with the frequent use of word.

Other words that commonly replaced "eww" as expressions of disgust were "sick", "gross" and "vile".

Another of the most frequently uttered words at school was "[minging](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19778/in-what-contexts-would-one-use-the-slang-word-minging-in-british-english)" (along with "minger" and "mings"). The word could be used both on its own as a reaction to experiencing something unpleasant ("minging!"), or as part of a sentence ("that looks/smells/tastes/feels minging"). This may well have been a northern thing as I don't remember friends and relatives in the south being familiar with it (at least at that time).

**Edit**: I need to add the ever-popular vomit noise "*blurgh*" to my list.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with this question is we're dealing with an orthographic representation of an "imitative/onomatopoeic" interjection. It's worth noting OED's two different pronunciations...

> Brit. **/ˈiː(j)uː/**
>     U.S. **/ˈi(j)u/**

OED list the alternative spellings *euuw, euuww, euuwww, euw, euww, euwww, eww, ewww*, and point out *"forms with **u** occurring three or more times or **w** occurring four or more times are also occasionally attested"*. All this for a "word" that apparently didn't even *exist* until 1975.

OP is clearly more interested in the history of the *sound itself* than whether or how it's written, but I do think it's worth noting that OED also says *compare **ugh, ough, ooh, oh***. I have to say that *none* of those forms seem to suggest the sound I personally usually make to indicate disgust (it's pretty much just an "extended neutral vowel", which I'd normally transcribe as ***eugh***).

I first noticed the "American high school girl" pronunciation (which is how I still feel about it) back in the late 90s, around the time I started using Internet chat forums. But it's quite likely that in all the fifteen years since then I personally have *never* made that sound myself (except facetiously, poking fun at people who *do* make it). On the other hand, I bet I've *written* it thousands of times in forum posts and "txt" messages - simply because it's quick, easily recognised, and "close enough".

Both my children (in their early 20s) definitely use the **/ˈiː(j)uː/** pronunciation from time to time, and one of them has just told me she thinks of it as "normal English" (not particularly "American"). But they grew up watching The Simpsons, so what do they know? They both sometimes answer the phone with *"Y'ello?"*, which so far as I'm concerned is a Homer Simpson affectation.

---

My point here is that it's very difficult to know exactly how other people pronounce words just by looking at what they *write*. They might be like me, just using the easiest or most common spelling because "accuracy" is unimportant or impossible to achieve. Or they may start off using the "affected" form facetiously to poke fun, but eventually get so used to it they use it "for real".

Or people may consciously attempt to imitate the sound they think is *suggested* by a particular orthography. On that specific point, when I started writing this section I had it in mind to point out that *no-one* ever pronounces ***hiccough*** the way you'd expect from how it's written. In support of which I was going to post [this audio link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPcO05wzOE4).

I swear to God I had to turn the volume up and listen *real* close to convince myself that "Emma" there really is saying *hick**uff***, because my "language processing" mental circuitry automatically switches it to *hick**up*** before anything reaches my conscious awareness. In matters of language, we tend to hear what we *expect* to hear (whether the source is actual sounds, or letters).

Comment: There isn't really any difference between the two IPA notations, is there? It's just that the OED doesn't believe in long symbols for vowels in American English (which makes sense, since we've mostly lost the long/short contrast in vowels).  But as an American, let me note that both of these vowels usually are much longer than the normal length of /i/ and /u/ in AmE.

Comment: @Peter: Yeah - I thought it was a bit odd that (to the extent one *could* say there's a difference in the IPA) they list the one with the more accentuated / elongated initial 'ee' component as "British". To my ear, the mere *presence* of that element seems essentially "American", and I agree with you that it's usually more "exaggerated" than the IPA would imply. I don't know if my "American high school girl" label has any justification beyond my personal "prejudice" though.

Answer (score 5):

This has definitely crossed! I would still associate it with a:

> scatterbrained beautiful blonde girl when she sees or hears something disgusting

often a reaction towards blood or something they object to - spiders and snakes (esp. when eating) often get an "*eew*".

I live in East Anglia, in a more affluent area, and because of that I don't hear as much of these Americanisation of our language - for example minging isn't often used in my earshot.

But yes, it has come across - long enough ago that I (15 years old) didn't realise it was an Americanisation - I don't remember life without it (same with google!).

Comment: Thank you for your contribution which I've upvoted. It's great to hear from someone so young, and "straight from the horse's mouth" too.

Comment: Though "minging" is a British word, not American. It's probably only used in some areas, though. When I was a child in Scotland it was common, but my kids, Londoners, would probably barely know it.

Answer (score 1):

These imitative sounds serve to express emotion and are a product of the facial expression that expresses the emotion. Traditionally psychologists worked with six basic emotions including fear and surprise. Theres a pic of these at http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/brain-and-cognitive-sciences/9-00sc-introduction-to-psychology-fall-2011/emotion-motivation/discussion-emotion/.

My point is that the 'ugh' sound (or blurgh or gross) is quite different to the politer 'eww' in which the lips are kept closer together. So I asked myself, if our American was using 'eww', what corresponding sound was being used by a Brit trying to be polite back in the 70s?

To find out, I revisited one of the iconic moments of British TV and the team of young men and women who taught a generation of UK children to speak, think and feel. The TV series is called Blue Peter and in this 1969 episode the presenters bring a juvenile elephant into the studio.

Despite being bathed in bodily fluids and trodden on, you will note that there is no 'urgh' or 'yuck' or 'aghh', but rather a couple of polite 'oh's. No 'eww' in sight in 1969!!

http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=N_Cj2TtFd_E

Enjoy !

Comment: Despite the iconic Blue Peter clip, which I enjoyed hugely (still makes me chuckle out loud), neither one of the children show's presenters looked particularly disgusted nor shocked. If anything, they were all amused and embarrassed by the incident. So, great little clip with perhaps a confirmation that *ewws* were not typically exclaimed by British speakers in the 60s or early 70s but I did ask for the earliest documented proof of an Englishman or woman uttering or blurting out a spontaneous *ew!* :)

Comment: Fair enough! Good luck ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In 1995/6 I was co-running an online MUD (a text-based adventure game), and was introduced to "ewww" by the multitude of American university students (largely West Coast) who played on our server.  I liked it immediately  and have been using it ever since.

Slightly tangentially, I was also introduced to "kewl" as a deliberately phonetic mis-spelling of "cool" via the same source, and its traditional mis-typing: "kwel".

So, in my experience, the word spread to my side of the pond via the internet.

I am 47, and a British English speaker.